# is Pareto distribution exponential dispersion family and the form is unique?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, exponential-family, pareto-distribution

I am trying to show that Pareto distribution with $$f(y;\alpha)=\alpha y^{-\alpha-1} $$ is exponential dispersion (ED) family which means that it can be rewritten as:
$$f(y;\theta,\phi)= \exp\left\{\frac {y\theta-b(\theta)} {a(\phi)} + c(y;\phi)\right\}$$ with $E[Y]=b^{\prime}(\theta)$ and $Var[Y]=b^{\prime\prime}(\theta)a(\phi).$

What I found is there are multiple ways to rewrite the PDF in the exponential dispersion family form, but since I know that $$E[Y]=\frac {\alpha} {\alpha-1}$$ and $$Var[Y]=\frac {\alpha} {(\alpha-1)^2(\alpha-2)},$$ I can solve the differential equations to get $$b(\theta)=\alpha + {\rm log}(\alpha-1)$$ and $$a(\phi)=\frac {-\alpha} {\alpha-2}.$$ This suggests that the form of $f(y;\theta,\phi)$ is unique.

So, is the ED family form of the PDF for Pareto distribution unique? If so, what is the correct form?

Comment: Your question is confusing as (a) you use three different notations for the parameter, ie $\alpha,\theta,\phi$ and (b) you use the same notation for $y$ in the Pareto and $y$ in the exponential family. Since $f(y;\alpha)=\exp\{\log(y)(-\alpha-1)+\log(\alpha)\}$, you get the natural representation. Note also that you are missing the indicator function in the Pareto density.

Comment: Thanks! (a) I forgot to mention that this is a reparameterization, we can find $\theta$ and $\phi$ in terms of $\alpha$ (b) yes, this is the natural form for exponential family, but not in the form of ED as I illustrated above. Yes, I skip the indicator function $I(Y>1)$.

Comment: You still didn't fix the missing indicator in the density.  We need to know the range!

Comment: Have you found the solution? Because, me either, I'm interested in showing that the GPD comes from EDM and I can't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You have given a Pareto density with a fixed lower limit of range 1,
$$ f(y; \alpha)= \alpha y^{-(\alpha+1)}, \quad y \ge 1
$$
Taking logarithms we can write this in exponential family form
$$f(y; \alpha)= \exp\left\{ -(\alpha+1)\log y + \log\alpha  \right\}
$$ which does not have any dispersion parameter, but introducing $\phi\equiv 1$ we can recognize the exponential dispersion family form as
$$f(y; \alpha)= \exp\left\{ -\frac{(\alpha+1)\log y}{\phi} + \log\alpha  \right\}
$$
so the answer is **yes**, the Pareto family with known lower limit of 1 is an exponential dispersion family with canonical statistic $\log y$. Note that $\log y$ does have an exponential distribution, see [Distribution of the exponential of an exponentially distributed random variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/554034/distribution-of-the-exponential-of-an-exponentially-distributed-random-variable)

And, yes, this form is unique.